# TSQL Distinct List of departments based on current user

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, distinct

I couldn't even think of how to phrase this properly for the title.

I have an SSRS report with a `multi-valued parameter` called `Department`.

> If the user **IS IN** `Department A`..We want to default to all departments EXCEPT  department A
>
> If the user **IS NOT IN** `Department A`..We want to default to only their department

**Department A will never be in the parameter list** but being a member of department A impacts what you will see.

> I know that I could resolve this with an `ALL` parameter option, but I would prefer the only parameter values to be valid department names

My parameter is populated with two datasets.
The first dataset has three options for valid departments: `EUR`, `REM`, `LIFA`

The second dataset only determines the current user's department and would populate the default. `IF` the current user's department is `CS` we want to select the other three departments as the default. If their department `<> CS` we want to default to only their department.

I thought the code below would work but the concatenated string is not an option in the first dataset so it cannot be the default option

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE
        WHEN EmployeePracticeArea = 'CS'
            THEN 'EUR, LIFA, REM'
        ELSE EmployeePracticeArea
    END AS 'EmployeePracticeArea'
FROM DimEmployee
WHERE
    (EmployeePracticeArea <> '')
    AND (UserLogin = @CurrentUser)
```

---

The problem with the case statement is that it tries to set a default value of `EUR, LIFA, REM`. This string does not exist in the 'options' list of values. The options are the three seperate strings `EUR`, `LIFA`, `REM`.

Case statements cannot return multiple values so I need to evaluate the current user's department and then return a list without it

> Here is something which will generate the dataset for you

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TestData;


WITH Data (EmployeePracticeArea) AS (
    SELECT 'LIFA'
    UNION
    SELECT 'REM'
    UNION
    SELECT 'EUR'
    UNION
    SELECT 'CS'
)

SELECT * INTO #TestData FROM Data ;
```

The end result is like this:
User1 in the LIFA department has his parameter defaulted to just LIFA
User2 in the CS department has his parameter defaulted to EUR, LIFA, REM

Comment: The `CASE` expression appears to be written correctly - I don't think I'm understanding what you're trying to do...  can you show sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Dept varchar(4))
DECLARE @CurrentUserDept varchar(4) = (SELECT EmployeePracticeArea FROM dimEmployee WHERE UserLogin = @CurrentUser)

IF @CurrentUserDept = 'CS'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('EUR'), ('LIFA'), ('REM')
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t SELECT @CurrentUserDept 
    END
SELECT * FROM @t
```

Comment: fantastic, thank you very much. I never use `IF` statements in my TSQL but I'll have to start

Comment: Glad I could help. I still learn lots of things on SO and I've been doing this job for decades! :)